# n-Tier Application and Helper Classes

Tags: java, architecture, n-tier-architecture

I am learning the n-tier application architecture and writing simple imitation of Console CMS on Java. Let's say I've already modeled my DAL and BLL layers. However, it's a console application with command-line so I have class that parse user's input. Let's suppose it to be 'helper'. Where in this 3-tier it should be located?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about layers or tiers?

Tiers are the physically separate components of the same system. On the other hand, layers refer to the internal architecture of your component.

Your console is app UI layer, and if viewed as a tier, it could be deployed to a dedicated machine, in the same machine where the BLL resides, in many different client machines, etc.. It depends on the performance needs of the application.